# Adicionar valores á uma gramatica ANTLR

Tags: semântica, paradigma-de-programação

Tenho uma gramática:

```
    grammar SimpleCalc;

expr : term ( ( '+' | '-' ) term )* ';' ;
term : number ;
number  : DIGIT+ ;  
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Saída:

```
    Parse Tree:
expr (
 term (
  number (
   "3"
  )
 )
 "+"
 term (
  number (
   "2"
  )
 )
 ";"
)
```

Para adicionar multiplicação e divisão, seria só fazer isso?

```
expr : term ( ( '+' | '-' ) term )* ';' ;
```

Estou um pouco perdido, se tiverem algum doc pra me ajudar seria ótimo